# How do I list multiple databases with their tables by using "Show Tables" via Java?

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to list MySQL databases and their tables with Java. For now, I have two databases as *"Database_Services* with *MySQL_Database_Service*, *MSSQL_Database_Service*, and *Directory_Services* with *Active_Directory*, *OpenLDAP* tables. I get the output for *Database_Services* and its tables but I do not get the other ones.

```
public class connectMySQL implements serverConnection{
Connection conn;
Statement stmt;
public void connect(String dbName){
    String url;
    try {
        if(dbName.equals("")){
            url = "jdbc:mysql://x:x/";
        }
        else{
            url = "jdbc:mysql://x:x”+ dbName;
        }
        String username = “x”;
        String password = "x";
        conn =  DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("An error occurred. Maybe user/password is invalid");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

```
public class listInf extends connectMySQL implements listInfrastructure {
public void list() {
    String dbName;
    ResultSet rs;
    try{
        connect("");
        String str = "SHOW DATABASES";
        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(str);
        while(resultSet.next()){
            dbName = resultSet.getString("Database");
            if(!dbName.contains("schema") && !dbName.equals("mysql")){
                System.out.println(dbName);
                rs = stmt.executeQuery("SHOW TABLES IN " + dbName);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println("\t" + rs.getString("Tables_in_" + dbName));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
```

}

I want to get an output like:

Database_Services:

1. MySQL_Database_Service.
2. MSSQL_Database_Service.

Directory_Services:

1. Active_Directory_Service.
2. OpenLDAP_Service.

Comment: Have you tried executing those statements without Java? Also please extend the code so that it is runnable. Where do you declare `rs` and `stmt`?

Comment: Yes, I did in my MySQL server and it's working.  I can list them both seperatly but i can not list them together at the same time. And I edited the post as you wanted.

Comment: Please do not vandalise your posts and remove the code. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large ([under the CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same `Statement` for multiple queries. You cannot do that. From the [Javadoc of `Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html):

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an open one exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
Connection conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
Connection conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

Statement statement1 = conn1.createStatement();
Statement statement2 = conn2.createStatement();

ResultSet resultSet1 = statement1.executeQuery("SHOW TABLES IN DB1");
ResultSet resultSet2 = statement2.executeQuery("SHOW TABLES IN DB2");

while (resultSet1.next()) {
   System.out.println("");
}

while (resultSet2.next()) {
   System.out.println("");
}
```

if you have more than 2 database, then simply you can use loop for to get the results.

Comment: That's basically what OP does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the meta information database `information_schema`.

```
SELECT 
    TABLE_SCHEMA,
    TABLE_NAME 

FROM information_schema.TABLES

WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('Database_Services', 'Directory_Services')

ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA
```